# Running grunt.file.copy returns Error code: ENOENT

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

I want to copy a directory to a different location using a Grunt task. I don't want this to be run in my default task, where copy is run, so I am registering a new task for it called "myTask" using the following code:

```
  grunt.registerTask('myTask', 'Make new dir and copy "src" there', function() {
    grunt.file.copy('src/*','../dest/');
  });
```

Whenever I run myTask, it tells me:

> Warning: Unable to read "src/*" file (Error code: ENOENT). Use --force to continue.

Is there a certain syntax I'm missing for the source directory I'm copying from?

Comment: I think that `grunt.file.copy()` might only copy files from one place to another, not whole directories. But besides that, why not have two different `grunt-contrib-copy` targets and specify which target is to be run in your `default` task?

Comment: @jakerella I'm not sure how to specify which copy target will be run in my default task. Wouldn't I just include them both in the grunt.initConfig function and they'd both run automatically? Also, it seems like I could just copy all files using grunt.file.copy("*.*") but that throws the same error.

Comment: Yeah, you can't use this function for copying directories or lists of files... only single files. I'll add an answer for how to use `copy` targets to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mention that you already use the `copy` task, but don't want to include this specific copying in your `default` task... so I would recommend using multiple targets in your config and just specifying which to perform in your `default` task array:

```
grunt.initConfig({
  copy: {
    js: {
      files: [{
        expand: true,
        src: ['path/to/js/*.js'],
        dest: 'dest/js'
      }]
    },
    otherstuff: {
      files: [{
        expand: true,
        src: ['src/**'],
        dest: 'dest/'
      }]
    }
  },
  // ...
});

// notice that in our default task we specify "copy:js"
grunt.registerTask('default', ['jshint', 'concat', /* etc, */ 'copy:js']);
```

Now you can run `~$ grunt copy:otherstuff` separately from `~$ grunt copy:js` and when you just run `~$ grunt` it will run the default task which only runs `copy:js`.